# Use single sql connection to fetch big data from sql server with Parrel Processing

Tags: .net, sql-server, architecture, bigdata

We have database with around 50000 users and around average 30000 orders per users. Sql Server database is production database many application already working in that database.

[image]

What we need ?

1. Need to upload all Users and their orders into nosql database.
2. Order can be add and modify when application running.
3. We need single connection pooling and parrel processing , its possible ?
4. Sql connection can be down any time, How to track uploaded orders and users ?
5. Orders data size is big so we can upload aprox 2000 order in one call into nosql database.
6. How to track which orders update when application running. ?
7. Suppose User A have 45000 orders and we uploaded 20000 orders now sql connection goes down , how we will track this ?

Comment: Too broad. 7 questions, not one. Seriously - obviously whoever came up with this idea (and runs a very bad infrastructure) has to consider hiring at least ONE senior developer / architect that is not clueless about the issues if complex system design. A Q&A site can not replace years of experience.

Comment: I doubt batch processing is the right solution. Have you considered messaging instead? Just publish durable messages on an enterprise service bus when orders/users are created/modified and have a single-threaded consumer or multiple competing consumers process the messages to bring the NoSQL data store consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you start in the SQL database, and the dump the data to NoSQL?  That is VERY backwards.  If you want the data in a relational model (for reporting and what-not), use the NoSQL database for user interactions, and do extract-and-load processes to dump it into the relational db.

The whole point in the No-sql db is to denormalize the data for high concurrency and performance.  Especially when you have a nice hierarchical data-model like user-> orders.